# "It is reported that ~" to "reported to infinitive ~"

Tags: to-infinitive

> It is reported that one ancient Greek athlete ate dried figs to enhance training.

Is the sentence above correct?
Can I change it to the sentence below?

> One ancient Greek athlete is reported to have eaten dried figs to enhance training.

Comment: Yes, both sentences are correct, and they have the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct:

> It is reported that one ancient Greek athlete ate dried figs to enhance training.

and

> One ancient Greek athlete is reported to have eaten dried figs to enhance training.

are both correct and have the same meaning.